# Environment variable expansion in GitHub Workflows

Tags: github-actions

Can the existing env variable definition be used to define another env variable?

EXAMPLE (snippet of GH Workflow):

```
  TOP_DOMAIN: com
  FQDN: example.${{ env.TOP_DOMAIN }}
```

What is the preferred way to do this? I know there is a way to do that using GH env files `GITHUB_ENV`, but more interested if there is some cleaner way without creating a new `run` step in a workflow.

Comment: Concatenation at the env level is a bit tricky. You can use expressions, but concatenation using other env variables doesn't work. I've made a POC [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/53-concatenation.yml) if you want to have a look. At the moment, you would need a `run` step to concatenate those values, and export them to the `GITHUB_ENV` file to use the joined value in other steps.